# Modal - Can't get close and @Input working with external component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use `@Input` with component but can't figure out how to send the variable when I click to open the modal. For example, I have the following template:

```
<template #modalContent>
    <my-component-with-content [var1]="val1"></my-component-with-content>
</template>
```

And when I click to open the modal:

```
<button type="button" (click)="open(modalContent)" class="btn btn-default">Open</button>
```

I'm also confused with the close function.

I've tried:

```
<template #modalContent let-close='close'>
    <my-component-with-content></my-component-with-content>
</template>
```

and in my-component-with-content (html) when I try to call `(click) = close("close")` I get the following error: self.context.close is not a function

So my question is how can I pass var1 when I click the open button and how can I pass the `close` function to the external component?

***Edit***: I'm using the [ng-bootstrap modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, this was achieved in Angular 2.0.1, ng-bootstrap alpha6

You can pass your close function into your component with:

`<template #modalContent let-c="close">
    <my-component [var1]="val1" [close]="c"></my-component>
</template>`

This lets you call the close function which is bound to modalContent. The input binding that you have specified for var1 means your input is being set from a variable named val1 in the parent component and therefore does not need to be passed on open as the first method you have listed should work.

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: "my-component",
template: "<h2>{{var1}}</h2>" +
    "<button (click)='close()'>Close</button>"
})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input()
    var1: string;

    @Input()
    close: Function;
}
```

And in my containing component declaration a public
`val1: string = "some thing";`

When I click the button to open it displays **some thing** with a button beneath which will close the modal template when it is pressed.